# How to write a SQL Query which retrieves all the rows with 2 condition on the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

How to write a SQL Query which retrieves all the rows with 2 condition on the same column?

I got a table with a column called type.
What I want to do is to list up all type of value "name".
But the type column also has a value called text.
So what I want to do is to list up all type of names, that has type text value.

How can I achieve this?

```
ID     Type     Value
1      Name    Name1
1      Text    "Hello"
2      Text    "Hello test"
2      Name    Name2
3      Name    Name3
4      Name    Name4
5      Name    Name5
```

I only want to return name value that has a type text.
The table has two types, what I want to do it to only return all of the type "Name" which has a type text

Expected result:

```
ID     Type     Value
1      Name    Name1
2      Name    Name2
```

Because these two are the only one with type "text" with a value.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: For me the question is unclear. Could you attach table example and expected output?

Comment: @jarlh updated.

Comment: @Tomasz updated.

Comment: Is that sample table data, or the expected result? We want both anyway.

Comment: @jarlh updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a self join:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join tablename t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.Type = 'Name'
  and t2.Type = 'Text'
```

Comment: they both are from the same table. I can test it out

Comment: The same table is used twice here, having t1 and t2 as _table aliases_.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
Select * from
(
select a.* from tbl a join tbl b
on a.ID = b.ID
where
a.Type = 'Name' and b.Type = 'Text'
) tb
where tb.Type = 'Name'
```

Comment: No, sorry... I've updated the description now, if it would make it easier.

Comment: No need for the  `or (a.Type = 'Name' and b.Type = 'Text')` condition, since the outer query has `where tb.Type = 'Name'`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = 'Name' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.type = 'Text'
             );
```

I would use `join` if I wanted to use any values from the "text" row.  However, if I only want the "name" row, then I think `exists` is a more direct translation of the logic.